# I Get a png image as a response from Qrcode monkey APi and i need to save that image in a folder in my backend (response.data is a png file )

Tags: node.js, express, qr-code

axios
.request(options)
.then(function (response) {
console.log("respones",response);
// fs.createWriteStream('src/util/tempImg',response.data)

```
    (async () => {
      const data = await download("https://qrcode-monkey.p.rapidapi.com/qr/custom", '../../Images/');
      console.log(data); // The file is finished downloading.
    })();
    
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.error(error);
  });
```

Comment: Please edit your question better, also are you able to store the image or not?

Comment: no i cannot store the image

Comment: You must check node package multer, this is highly likely to be used for this purpose only. Storing media can on node server can be done using multer.